# Import MySQL database to excel with all tables in separate sheets

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Do you know how can I export whole MySQL database to Excel with maintaining table structure? I can use phpMyAdmin or Linux command line. If I use CSV I get table below table, so it's rather inefficient.
I tried XML, but Excel can't read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this extension [phpExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) .

> which allow you to write to and read from different spreadsheet file
>   formats, like Excel (BIFF) .xls, Excel 2007 (OfficeOpenXML) .xlsx,
>   CSV, Libre/OpenOffice Calc .ods, Gnumeric, PDF, HTML, ... This project
>   is built around Microsoft's OpenXML standard and PHP.

**Update**
If you asking a tool My suggestion  is [NaviCat](http://www.navicat.com/)

Comment: Of particular interest to RobM: **[Creating a new sheet](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/281184)**

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for some out of the box solution. I just need a one time export big database (not big but many tables) to Excel not writing script. Sth painless needed :)

Comment: @RobM Then try this tool http://www.navicat.com/products/navicat-for-mysql. I never used excel export but it has that feature.

Comment: @Shanoop thx, installing. Hope it will be better than Mysql Workbench which doesn't have export other than sql :P

Comment: @RobM If it worked accepting answer is well appreciated.

Comment: @Shanoop Navicat doesn't work as I wanted - tables in sheets, but it puts each table to a new xls file. However it's much better than one big csv file. Thank you.